# Can spark streaming pick specific files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

My program continuously read streams from a `hadoop` folder(say `/hadoopPath/`) .Its picking all the files from the above folder . Can I pic only specific file types for this folder ( like `:/hadoopPath/*.log`)

I have another question related to Spark and streaming :
[Is spark streaming works with both "cp" and "mv"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350336/is-spark-streaming-works-with-both-cp-and-mv)

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yaa I did ...Spark streaming is not picking the file for me ..I thought may be I am missing some configuration

Comment: Resolved the issue : Reffered to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350336/is-spark-streaming-works-with-both-cp-and-mv/36888900#36888900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been struggling with the same problem for a couple of hours and although it seemed so easy, I could not find anything online about it. Finally, I found a solution that worked in my case. I am putting it here to save some time for others with the same issue.
Consider you only want to read the files with the pattern "path-to-hadoop-folder/*.csv". In the default case, when you indicate the folder spark reads all the files in the folder (e.g. .csv.*COPYING*) which in my case, resulted in an error.  All you need to do is to specify this pattern in your .csv method when defining the readStrem. An example in python would be like this:

```
activity = spark \
    .readStream \ 
    .option("sep", ",") \ 
    .schema(userSchema) \ 
    .csv("path-to-hadoop-folder/*.csv")
```

In this way spark only considers files with *.csv pattern and ignores all other files that are in the folder. I have tested it on spark 2.0.0 and hadoop 2.6. (P.S I have only tested it for csv files but I guess working with text files should have a similar solution) 
you can find the same solution in [spark dataStreamReader guild](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader)

Comment: Is it introduced in spark 2.0.0 .I tried the same with 1.5 it was not working