# How to use spark streaming from a file system input

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to use spark streaming and give the input from file system (say HDFS ).How will I do it

Comment: You can use both cp and mv commands to transfer filesRefer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350336/is-spark-streaming-works-with-both-cp-and-mv/36888900#36888900

Comment: did you check the documentation? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-sources

Answer (score 1):

For instance, when using `JavaStreamingContext` there are appropriate methods methods, e.g. `textFileStream()` to read any text files, `fileStream()` to read files from Hadoop-compatible filesystem. The directory you pass as a parameter of the API will be monitored for changes. In case you are going to move any file there it will be picked up by Streaming application depending on batch interval.

Please have a look at my simple samples at [github](https://github.com/tmatyashovsky/lambda-architecture-jeeconf-kyiv/) to read data either from Twitter or from file system.

Hope that will help.